# Adding array elements to popup based on index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm relatively new to JS and JQuery. I want to add an element to the `$('.popUp')` div every time the mouse hovers over an `$('li')`. This should add the element from `array` whose index matches the number of the `$('li')` that was hovered over, i.e. if I hover over `li[0]`, I want `array[0]`('Bob') to appear in the `$('.popUp')` div.

```js
let array = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Kenny', 'Bill']
$('li').on('mouseover', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $('.popUp').html(array[i])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='popUp'></div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.index()` method to get the index of the element.

```js
let array = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Kenny', 'Bill']
$('li').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(".popUp").html(array[$(this).index()]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='popUp'></div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is important to notice that you didn't use the fat arrow notation for the function, so you had the correct "this" reference to event target.

Comment: Thank you so much, Vikram Singh! And thanks to @Professore for the much needed clarification. One further question: I have multiple identical divs with the same amount of `li`s and `popUp`s. I want to write a single piece of code to run my array through all the `li`s but the `li` index reverts to 0 whenever a new `ul` starts. How do I get around this?

Comment: You can add an id to the li element that will represent the index in the array. When you hover over the li you can get the id and can set the html. Or you can also get the index of the wrapping div and based on that you need to calculate the index.

Comment: Ok, I can get it to work if I do a lengthy if/else statement that target the wrapping divs and calculates the indexes. Did you have a more concise way of doing it in mind?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class='popUp'></div>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
</div>

 let array = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Kenny', 'Bill']
   $('li').on('mouseover', function(){

     var $index = $(this).index();    
     $('.popUp').html(array[$index]);

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `this` object

```
let array = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Kenny', 'Bill']
$('li').on('mouseover', () => {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('.popUp').html(array[index])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the array to create the names in the list, then its as simple as getting the text of each li on the hover and passing that to the div.

**Note that without passing something into the actual li - you will not have any text in the list - only empty li's with the bullet point.**

```js
let array = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Kenny', 'Bill'];


array.forEach(function(item){
  $('#names').append('<li>'+ item + '</li>');
})

 $('body').on('mouseover','li', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('.popUp').html(text)

 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class='popUp'>f</div>
    <ul id="names"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```js
let array = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Kenny', 'Bill']

$("ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).on('mouseover',()=> {
         var indx = $('ul li').index(this);
         $('.popUp').html(array[indx])
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='popUp'></div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```